# I followed the django example exactly. But it doesn't work

Tags: python, django

**
I followed the django example exactly. But it doesn't work. Web page just show the rocket to me.**

my project name: web

app name: main

## web.settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
]
```

web.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('main/', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

main.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

main.views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

I hope web page shows "Hello, world. You're at the polls index." to me.

Comment: You followed *what* example exactly?

Comment: Are your files literally named `main.urls.py` etc? Or is it `main/urls.py`?

Comment: I followed example that is django official web site. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/4.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: my files name is 'urls.py'. It's in 'main' package.

Answer (score 1):

In your main urls file you have set:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('main/', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Which actually means, that you need to go for `localhost:8000/main` for your urls in "main" app. If you want to do it without specifying `main` in the url in your browser, then change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Oh thanks to your comment. I change my urls.py. But it doesn,t work too....

Comment: @김석범 The answer is right, try to restart server correctly, and also Stack Overflow is a place for asking good questions, the real problems in which you're stuck, not for the basic tutorial.